# How to host my Java application in tomcat and then input data from an android app?

Tags: java

I have written a java program which connects to a database and runs some machine learning algorithm.
The query for the learning algorithm is sent via a android device. So I suppose I need to host this application of a server. 
Can someone direct me how to do it.
I have tomcat running in my machine. 
1.Where to put my java code in the server?
2.How do I made a java code to be able to handle Http requests?

Comment: I just leave it here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-overview.htm, http://tomcat.apache.org/, http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html. Keywords: Java servlet, servlet container.